# Installing BEM++ module on OS X - cmake/path

Tags: python, cmake

I am trying to install BEM++ on a OS X, following [this tutorial](http://www.bempp.org/installation.html). I am doing the final part, and i have to use the code

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install_dir> ..
```

I am supposed to change the 'install_dir' text for the direction in which bempp is installed, but i keeps telling me i am wrong.

[image]

What direction should a i put in?
Currently i think the path is something like

Macintosh HD/Users/adolfovillalobosvega/bempp/python/bempp

Macintosh HD/Users/adolfovillalobosvega/bempp/build

During the installation, we make a lot of "bempp" folders. Could you help me finding out what is the path?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your path inside `<` and `>`. They are supposed to mark meta language.

In your case this would be

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="Macintosh HD/Users/adolfovillalobosvega/bempp/build" ..
```

Comment: And make sure you delete your CMakeCache.txt file or your complete build directory.

Comment: @AdolfoVillalobosVega If you think other might profit from this answer, please consider accepting it (click on the checkmark) or even upvoting.